# Truncate string and add "..." only if more than 40 characters

Tags: magento-1.9

I have this code for the product description on the category page:

```
<?php echo substr($_product->getShortDescription(),0,40).'...'; ?>
```

But this code will show the ... always, even if the text length is 25 characters. How can I modify this code to show the ... only if the text is longer than 40 characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use magentos built-in method `Mage_Core_Helper_String::truncate()`

```
/**
 * Truncate a string to a certain length if necessary, appending the $etc string.
 * $remainder will contain the string that has been replaced with $etc.
 *
 * @param string $string
 * @param int $length
 * @param string $etc
 * @param string &$remainder
 * @param bool $breakWords
 * @return string
 */
public function truncate($string, $length = 80, $etc = '...', &$remainder = '', $breakWords = true)
{
    ...
}
```

Like ...

```
echo Mage::helper('core/string')->truncate($_product->getShortDescription(), 40);
```